# how to get the li element on button dropdown clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn addon-button" toggle-dropdown>
    <button type="button" class="button-m button-default dropdown-toggle http-button copyInput" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border-right:none !important;">
      <span id="addresstype" class="custom-input">Http://</span>
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-m dropdown-menu-m-small custom-dropdown-withInput w-100 p-0">
      <li id="Http://">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" value="selected">Http://</a>
      </li>
      <li id="Https://">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" value="selected">Https://</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

What javascript code or directive to be used?

Comment: You question is unclear. What exactly do you need to do? How are the `li` elements related to the button? Looking at your HTML, it would appear that the dropdown should open, once the button is clicked. What else should happen once the button is clicked? Do you want to get all of the `li` elements within that dropdown?

Comment: when clicked on li element ...then the selected  li element should be on button
ex: when i select the https from dropdown then when dropdown closes https label should be present on button

Comment: Ah, so you want to change `span#addressType.text`? If that's the case, just attach the `click` event listener to both of the `li` elements, and once the click is triggered, change the span text to what's in the clicked `li`.